# What's the difference between Start Debugging and Start Without Debugging in Silverlight Application?

Tags: debugging, silverlight-3.0, silverlight.fx

I have a problem wherein I get an AmbiguousMatchException in some of the samples from the Silverlight.FX samples.

The TaskList.aspx sample for example demonstrates this problem when I run Start Debugging the exception gets hit on line 202 in ListView.cs

```
FrameworkElement uiItem = itemTemplate.LoadContent() as FrameworkElement;
```

Except this problem doesn't show up when I Start Without Debugging. If I am debugging it will not succeed and create an item. But Without debugging it will.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess that the exception is being caught some where up the stack and you don't see it without the debugger being attached. Under Debug>Exceptions there are options for changing the way exceptions are handled when running under debug.

Comment: Yeah understood. But while running in debug I see it caught I see it travel up but it will not complete the task.. without debug it works.